# Splines and Gaussians

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, math

Higher-order splines all mostly look like Gaussians. I wonder how higher-order splines (from 3rd order onwards) and Gaussians differ.  How can one  differentiate them?

Comment: They are actually different because 3rd order splines are only twice differentiable whereas Gaussians are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: By "differentiate" do you mean "take the derivative of them" or "distinguish between them" ?

Comment: Could add some details about  the context you are asking this question in?

Comment: Exponential splines are new type of splines developed from one sided exponents, from this idea I had designed a new type splines from double sided exponents, In a recent conference one question was asked how my spline is different from standard Gaussians..

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about standard splines, piecewise polynomial, without tricks like orthogonalisation, they ought to have finite support. Not the case with Gaussians. As said by @Atul Ingle, derivability is another criterion, but might be more difficult to address on discrete data.